# PS4 loses internet connectivity with an app while remaining online

Tags: ps4, psn

My PS4 suddenly began kicking me off of whatever im watching (PlayStation Vue, Netflix, Internet Browser) but remains connected to the internet. The video will stop and then the app begins lagging pretty hard. After it stops working, I close the app and go to the network settings to test my connection and its fine every time.

After I test the internet connection, I re-open the app and it works fine for a few minutes, then it happens again.

This just started happening today, but it happens every few minutes or so. Also, my internet works on all my other devices.

Any advice would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Also, when I test my connection, my download speed is fine but my upload speed is around 215 kbps.